# TYPO3 links from non-https to http

Tags: .htaccess, http, https, typo3, base-url

**Goal:** Every non-https link has to become https. Always.

**Achieved by now:**

- Changed base-url to https
- Each link is https IF I'm on non-http

My issue is stated at my second achievement. For some reasons the links targets to https if I am on a non-https page, otherwise to http. I know I could implement a work-around using .htaccess but this isn't the clean way and I want to implement it in a clean way.

**What I've done to fix it:**

I know one can force the protocoll for a single typo3 page and I can update all pages via database but in this case it's not possible as it's a multitree presentation and not every tree have to use https.

I also googled and read about config.baseUrl but I've changed that before I even googled.

On the presentation "Enforce https" having key "https" is installed but I can't find it in the Ext. Repository.

**Further stuff:**

I guess the issue is not caused by .htaccess but in any case: This in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.de$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.mydomain.de/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in TYPO3? It's quite easy to do this in the server configuration (e.g. `.htaccess`). Also if the first page is forced to use TLS via server configuration, and all links use the same protocol the page was opened with, all links that are ever presented to the user are `https://`-links. You can filter by domain in your rewrite-rules, or use different vHosts for different domains.

Comment: It makes more sense to provide correct links in html dom than provide wrong links and redirect afterwards. Another bad side-effect of setting the rootpage protocoll only is when someone requests a subpage with http-protocoll.

Comment: But you are providing the correct links - there will never be a DOM delivered using HTTP, because the redirect occurs before that. So the user only gets DOMs with HTTPS-links. And you can't prevent someone entering your URL using `http://` manually.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. Mhm, I just checked the urls in the menu e.g. and noticed they are not relative but absolute :O This shouldn't be the case => I'll investigate that.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

The solution is to deactivate the Extension "https" which is installed in the TYPO3 presentation. *Why?* Well, for some reasons the extension replaces/renders the urls as absolute and which is even more weird with "http".

I proceed with the investigation and update the post later on with in depth details.